# How can you change position of labels in plot

Tags: plotting, graphics, labeling

Is it possible to change the location of number labels on the x-axis? On the plot below, created with `Show` (3 Plots, 6 ListLinePlots), I would like to move the Temperature tick labels (5, 10, etc.) from below the x-axis to above that axis.

I can share my code if necessary, but mainly I would like to know if there is a built-in function to specify label position relative to the axes?

[image]

Comment: Would you be interested in a `Frame` based solution?

Comment: Any solution is welcome, but if it is possible, i would like to keep it as simple as it can be

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A plot that looks like the one in the picture posted in OP:

```
Plot[{1, 3, 5}, {x, 0, 35}, ImageSize -> Medium, Filling -> Axis,
  PlotRange -> {All, {0, 6}}, ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Reverse"}, 
  AxesLabel ->  {"T[°C]", z[mm]}]
```

[image]

**1.** If it's not essential to have axes labels positioned at the ends, simplest approach is using `Frame` and `` Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}] `` to create horizontal axis ticks:

```
Plot[{1, 3, 5}, {x, 0, 35}, 
 Filling -> Axis, PlotRange -> {All, {0, 6}}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Reverse"}, 
 FrameLabel -> {{z[mm], None}, {None, T[Row[{Degree , "C"}]]}}, 
 Frame -> {{True, False}, {False, True}}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, 
   {Automatic, Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}]}}]
```

[image]

Use `` Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}][0, 35, {8, 6}] `` to get

[image]

**2.** Alternative approach with more detailed control over positioning and styling of ticks and labels is to use [`AxisObject`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AxisObject.html):

Create a version without the horizontal axis:

```
plot = Plot[{1, 3, 5}, {x, 0, 35}, ImageSize -> Medium, 
  Filling -> Axis, Axes -> {False, True}, PlotRange -> {All, {0, 6}}, 
  ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Reverse"}, AxesLabel ->  {None, z[mm]}, 
  Ticks -> {None, Automatic}]
```

[image]

and use [`AxisObject`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AxisObject.html) to construct an axis with desired features:

```
xaxis = Graphics @ AxisObject[Line[{{0, 0}, {35, 0}}], {0, 35}, 
    AxisLabel -> "  T[°C]", 
    TickPositions -> {{Range[5, 35, 5]}, {Range[35]}}, 
    AxisStyle -> Black, 
    TicksStyle -> {Black, Thickness -> Absolute[0.5]}, 
    TickLabelPositioning -> "Tip", 
    TickLengths -> {.15, .07}]
```

[image]

Combine `plot` and `xaxis` using `Show`:

```
Show[plot, xaxis]
```

[image]

Remove the option `TickLabelPositioning -> "Tip"` and add the option `TickDirection -> Down` in definition of `xaxis` above to get

[image]